# Delphi Windows Service Unable to Create Folders - But Function Returns True?

Tags: windows, delphi, service

I have a procedure in a data module that I use in both a Delphi ISAPI DLL and Windows Service for copying all the files in a specified folder into a new folder. The code is something like this:

```
if DirectoryExists(OldPath) then
    begin
        ForceDirectories(NewPath);
        lFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(OldPath);
        for I := 0 to Length(lFiles) - 1 do
            TFile.Copy(OldPath + TPath.GetFileName(lFiles[I]), NewPath + TPath.GetFileName(lFiles[I]));
    end;
```

The code works perfectly in the ISAPI DLL, and finishes without erroring in the service, but nothing is created. I've tried outputting the result of ForceDirectories, which returns True indicating it thinks the folder was created...

The other strange thing the service is doing, is often when I start it Windows seems to not realise it has started successfully so it will start another instance, then kill the first.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Are your path strings terminated with ```'\'```? If you are going to use `TPath`, then you may as well use `TPath.Combine()` when joining paths segments. Otherwise, at least use `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter()` instead. Aside from that, is the service running as `SYSTEM` or as a user? Try using [SysInternal Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what is really happening on the filesystem, I'm guessing that the files are not actually being saved where you are expecting them to go.

Comment: Hi Remy! Yes, my path strings are terminated with `'\'`. I've just tried using `ForceDirectories(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(NewPath))` and that didn't change anything. The service is running as `SYSTEM`. I can see in Process Monitor that it tries to create the folder but the result is "NAME NOT FOUND" followed by a "REPARSE".

Comment: Well, the `NAME NOT FOUND` happens when `ForceDirectories()` discovers a folder that it has to create (you should see the create happen after the `NOT FOUND` message), but does your target path actually contain [Reparse Points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-points) in it that map to other folders on your system?

Comment: Ah yes I see, the Disposition is Open for the first CreateFile operation while it's Create for the second that was getting a Result of REPARSE. However it seems like Avast was the problem... I added an exception for the folder and then everything worked fine. However I've now removed the exception and it's still working, but that's probably Avast being slow. Thanks for pointing me to Process Monitor however as that is very helpful. Do you have any idea why Windows starts the service twice a lot of the time?

Comment: "*Do you have any idea why Windows starts the service twice a lot of the time?*" - that is a completely different and unrelated question that should be asked in a new post.

Comment: Hint1: DirectoryExists() and ForceDirectories() are redundant. Use ForceDirectories() only because it already checks if the dir exists. Hint2: TDirectory and TFile are *extremely* buggy. Use the old versions of the funtions from SysUtils or Windows API directly.

Comment: Avast was also responsible for the double starting, so ultimately this question was all just antivirus problems! Alexandre, I use DirectoryExists for OldPath because if it doesn't I don't want to create NewPath. But I'll have a look into the SysUtils functions. Thanks for all the help both.